# glype proxy script with squid optimising web Delivery

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to utilize [squid : Optimising Web Delivery](http://www.squid-cache.org/) with [Glype® Proxy Script](https://www.glype.com/).

`include/init.php` (`Custom browser - set up defaults`):

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['custom_browser']) ) {
        $_SESSION['custom_browser'] = array(
                'user_agent'    => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '',
                'referrer'              => 'real',
                'tunnel'                => '127.0.0.1',
                'tunnel_port'   => '3128',
                'tunnel_type'   => 'http',
        );
}
```

... yet, proxy works even if i stop squid (i.e. `tunnel_*` is *NOT* how you set it up).

anyone else dealt with it? I definitely remember it was working a while back ...

Answer (score 0):

ahh, I actually found it))

`browse.php` (`Prepare the REQUEST`) (line 304):

```
$toSet[CURLOPT_PROXYPORT] = 3128;
$toSet[CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE] = "HTTP";
$toSet[CURLOPT_PROXY] = "127.0.0.1";
```